# XBox recognizes my USB, but shows it as empty

Tags: xbox-360

I have formatted my usb and the xbox recognizes it, however, it shows the usb as empty which it is not. Why is this? What can I do?

Comment: Can you explain a) how you formatted the USB drive and b) what you are expecting to see on the drive?

Comment: You do realize that formatting a drive generally erases the data that's on it, right?

Comment: Didn't your Xbox *warn* you of the consequences of formatting? I've never seen a formatting feature *not* featuring a warning message like: "Formatting the drive will erase all data. This process is irreversible"

Answer (score 4):

If you format a drive, it erases all the contents of the drive.

Now that it is formatted, you can put all your files back on it. They will then show up properly (unless you format it again).

In the future, make sure you understand the consequences of formatting. You can use this tool to change the filesystem of a drive, however data can not persist between filesystem changes.

Comment: god bless this answer , helped me , thank you ^^ B